# Paste column content by group into a new group

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is my data frame:

```
a <- data.frame(x=c(rep("A",2),rep("B",4)),
                y=c("AA","BB","CC","AA","DD","AA"))
```

What I want is group the data frame by `x` and for each member of the group (here `A` or `B`), I would like to paste the content of column `y` into a single element, separated by `_`. I would like to sort it by alphabetical order and remove identical characters. Here is the desired result:

```
out <- data.frame(x=c(rep("A",1),rep("B",1)),
                y=c("AA_BB","AA_CC_DD"))
```

I tried the following code, which produces an error message:

```
library(dplyr)

a %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(y_comb=paste(as.character(sort(unique(y))))) %>% 
      slice(1) %>% ungroup()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We get the `distinct` element of 'x', 'y' column (as there is only two columns, simply use `distinct` on the entire data), then `arrange` the rows by 'x', 'y' column, grouped by 'x', paste (`str_c`) the 'y' elements into a single string by `collapse`ing with `_`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
a %>% 
   distinct %>% 
   arrange(x, y) %>% 
   group_by(x) %>%
   summarise(y = str_c(y, collapse="_"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  x     y       
#* <chr> <chr>   
#1 A     AA_BB   
#2 B     AA_CC_DD
```

---

The error in OP's code is because of the difference in `length` after doing the `unique` and `paste` by itself doesn't do anything.  We need to either `collapse` (or `sep` - in this case it is `collapse`). `mutate` is particular about returning the same `length` as the number of rows of original data while `summarise` is not

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps we can do like this

```
a %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(y = paste0(sort(unique(y)), collapse = "_"))
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  x     y       
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     AA_BB
2 B     AA_CC_DD
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R option with `aggregate` :

```
aggregate(y~x, unique(a), function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = '_'))

#  x        y
#1 A    AA_BB
#2 B AA_CC_DD
```